# Change value depending on if + else if + else

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to change the values in a column "final" depending on the value of 2 other columns "source1" + "source2" like this:

```
if (source1 == 1) > final = 1,
else if (source2 == 1) > final = 1,
else > final = 0.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using `case_when()`

Comment: I can't decipher what you are trying to do here. Can you write out your logic and inputs / outputs in words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you did not provide a reprex (https://reprex.tidyverse.org/),
but I shall try to answer to the best of my knowledge.

To me it seems like want to modify a column of a given data.frame. You can easily do so by combining the `mutate` function and the `case_when` function from the `dplyr` package.

But, be careful: You have to make sure there are no contradictions in your clauses. You could achieve the same result with nested `ifelse`s statements.

Here is a small reprex, which you can modify to fit your needs.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

head(iris)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

iris_mod <- iris %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Petal.Width = case_when(
    Species == "setosa" ~ Petal.Width + 0.5,
    Species == "virginica" ~ Petal.Width - 0.5
  ))

head(iris_mod)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.7  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.7  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.7  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.7  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.7  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.9  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Sorry for my late response - this works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two conditions using `||`; so for single values you could write

```
result = if (source1 == 1 || source2 == 1) 1 else 0
```

However, since you want to apply the test to multi-value *vectors* of values rather to single values, you need to use `ifelse` and `|` instead:

```
final = ifelse(source1 == 1 | source2 == 1, 1, 0)
```

And you should also consider whether using logical values (`TRUE`, `FALSE`) isn’t more appropriate than using numeric values. In which case you can write:

```
final = source1 == 1 | source2 == 1
```

Or even (coding `source1` and `source2` as logicals, too):

```
final = source1 | source2
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment - I decided for the case_when function!